# Click first cell on table with no ID and no A tag

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vb.net-2010

i'm trying to click on the first cell of a table with no ID and no A tag. Once the first cell is clicked, i'm prompted to download a zip file. I will then extract the zip file and import the csv file that was extracted, into a MySQL Table. I have everything done except for clicking on the first cell. I just need help on clicking on the first cell to download the file. Please help.

Here's a screenshot of the table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZBnY.jpg

Table header

```
<table class="htCore">
<colgroup>
  <col class="rowHeader" style="width: 50px;">
  <col style="width: 90px;">
  <col style="width: 147px;">
  <col style="width: 144px;">
  <col style="width: 208px;">
  <col style="width: 512px;">
</colgroup>
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th class="" style="height: 25px;">
        <div class="relative"><span class="colHeader cornerHeader">&nbsp;</span></div>
     </th>
     <th class="">
        <div class="relative"><span class="colHeader columnSorting">Operation</span></div>
     </th>
     <th class="">
        <div class="relative"><span class="colHeader columnSorting">Requested ID</span></div>
     </th>
     <th class="ht__highlight">
        <div class="relative"><span class="colHeader columnSorting">Requested Date</span></div>
     </th>
     <th class="ht__highlight">
        <div class="relative"><span class="colHeader columnSorting">Status</span></div>
     </th>
     <th class="ht__highlight">
        <div class="relative"><span class="colHeader columnSorting">RequestInfo</span></div>
     </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

The Body

```
<tbody>
      <tr>
     <th class="ht__highlight ListView_Current">
        <div class="relative"><span class="rowHeader">1</span></div>
     </th>
     <td class="htDimmed ListView_Current">M/R</td>
     <td class="htDimmed ListView_Current">20190127220652968</td>
     <td class="htDimmed highlight">01/27/2019 22:06:52</td>
     <td class="htDimmed highlight">Completed</td>
     <td class="htDimmed highlight">(FileName,DNBCC_MGMR_20190127220652968.zip),(FileSize,721234),(SiteName,Atlantic, Tomorrows Office),(Depot Name,),(CSV Separator,,),(Download to,Your PC),(CSV Type,Detail),(Search Range(MM/DD/YYYY),01/21/2019-01/27/2019),(Customer,),(Device S/N,),(Vendor,)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th class="">
        <div class="relative"><span class="rowHeader">2</span></div>
     </th>
     <td class="htDimmed">M/R</td>
     <td class="htDimmed">20190127220158966</td>
     <td class="htDimmed">01/27/2019 22:01:58</td>
     <td class="htDimmed">Completed</td>
     <td class="htDimmed">(FileName,DNBCC_MGMR_20190127220158966.zip),(FileSize,721249),(SiteName,Atlantic, Tomorrows Office),(Depot Name,),(CSV Separator,,),(Download to,Your PC),(CSV Type,Detail),(Search Range(MM/DD/YYYY),01/21/2019-01/27/2019),(Customer,),(Device S/N,),(Vendor,)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th class="">
        <div class="relative"><span class="rowHeader">3</span></div>
     </th>
     <td class="htDimmed">M/R</td>
     <td class="htDimmed">20190127215611964</td>
     <td class="htDimmed">01/27/2019 21:56:11</td>
     <td class="htDimmed">Completed</td>
     <td class="htDimmed">(FileName,DNBCC_MGMR_20190127215611964.zip),(FileSize,721257),(SiteName,Atlantic, Tomorrows Office),(Depot Name,),(CSV Separator,,),(Download to,Your PC),(CSV Type,Detail),(Search Range(MM/DD/YYYY),01/21/2019-01/27/2019),(Customer,),(Device S/N,),(Vendor,)</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried the following but i get a System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement.InnerText.get returned nothing error:

```
Dim tables As HtmlElementCollection = 
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div") - also "table"
    For Each tbl As HtmlElement In tables
        For Each row As HtmlElement In tbl.All
            For Each cell As HtmlElement In row.All
                If Not cell.Style Is Nothing Then
                    If cell.InnerText.Contains("M/R") Then - also tried InnerHtml
                        cell.InvokeMember("click") 
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

And also the javascript:

```
function downloadFile(fileName, fileSize) {
var downloadForm = $('<form 
action="https://ssd.support.thewebsite.com/atremotecenter/DL" method="get">
<input type="text" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"/><input type="text" name="Accept-Encoding" value="gzip"/>
<input type="text" name="X-NRS-User-ID" value="myusername"/><input type="text" name="X-NRS-Certificate" value="iHmkmuotsGXfYF/VVp8U5l5YT68pNywANPF7Hk1FH8zUyWPFWPdQ7LwCyJcubSjhDegily9s+CgO5r+ip8aWZnuqeyWKYG2uXnb0KXgV8To0sxmCHIjNPedSBgzHUNK0W5eZeoeUP02w8TpBoPsF4g=="/>
<input type="text" name="X-NRS-File-Name" value="'+fileName+'"/> . 
<input type="text" name="Range" value="bytes=0-'+(fileSize-1)+'"/> . 
</form>').hide().appendTo('body');
downloadForm.submit();
downloadForm.remove();
return false;
}
```

Comment: I do not see any events tied to the cell. Are you missing some javascript? Is this everything tied to the page?

Comment: I just added the javascript

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for.
You will need to put a webbrowser control on your Windows Form.

In Your calling form/event put the following code to help set up the webbrowser:

```
    'WebBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = [.NET object]  
    WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    WebBrowser1.AllowNavigation = True
```

Then, Call the navigate function of the webbrowser:

```
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.example.com")
```

Finally, in the Webbrowser1.documentCompleted event put the following:

```
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Dim strFileName As String
        Dim lngFileSize As Long

        'You will still need to get this information from the html contents of the table.
        strFileName = "DNBCC_MGMR_20190127215611964.zip"
        lngFileSize = 721257

        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("downloadFile", {strFileName, lngFileSize})
    End Sub
```

Comment: The [`ObjectForScripting` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting?view=netframework-4.7.2) doesn't take a boolean. It expects a custom .NET object (class) which it exposes to the browser's JavaScript engine, thus allowing it to be accessed directly from the JavaScript code as well. It's important to read the docs or at least check IntelliSense before using a property to see what it actually expects (for instance if it expects an `Object` then a bool is most likely not the right choice).

Comment: Otherwise a good solution invoking the JavaScript directly, if the OP already has the expected values!

Comment: @VisualVincent my bad. I had used that property as a simple Boolean. You are correct, I should have more thoroughly checked the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your table has set its `class` attribute you can use that to identify it. Then it's just a matter of getting the first `<tbody>` and the first `<tr>` inside that.

```
'Iterate all elements with the "htCore" class.
For Each htCore As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByClassName("htCore")
    'Check if the element is a table.
    If htCore.TagName.Equals("table", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then

        'Get all <tbody> elements in the table.
        Dim tbodies As HtmlElementCollection = htCore.GetElementsByTagName("tbody")
        If tbodies.Count > 0 Then

            'Get all <tr> elements in the first body.
            Dim rows As HtmlElementCollection = tbodies(0).GetElementsByTagName("tr")
            If rows.Count > 0 Then
                'Invoke click on the first row.
                rows(0).InvokeMember("click")
                Exit For 'Stop looping.
            End If

        End If

    End If
Next
```